# Magento grouped block won't load my custom theme file grouped.phtml

Tags: magento

I have a custom magento theme that is working fine for a while now. Recently the client wanted to add grouped products, and now I need to change the layout so it will fit.

Here is my problem:
When I look at the page with template path hints turned on, pretty much everything uses my custom template, like this:

```
frontend/[MYTEMPLATE]/default/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml
frontend/[MYTEMPLATE]/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml
frontend/[MYTEMPLATE]/default/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml
```

etc... etc...

However, for the grouped products, the following is used:

```
frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml
```

I copied that grouped.phtml to my template folder using the same structure, but it isn't loaded.

My catalog.xml shows the following:

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped translate="label" module="catalog">
  <label>Catalog Product View (Grouped)</label>
  <reference name="product.info">
    <block type="catalog/product_view_type_grouped" name="product.info.grouped" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml">
      <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.grouped.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
        <label>Product Extra Info</label>
      </block>
    </block>
  </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
```

Caching is turned off.

I'm sure I'm missing something here on why it isn't using the grouped.phtml from my template folder, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: double check the file path in your theme. If it's not loaded from your theme it means it doesn't exist in there

Comment: This must be the dumbest thing I've done in a while... You are right, I missed the extra /type/ folder, and placed the grouped.phtml one folder up.